# Adding a decimal point at the second mark in a data frame

Tags: r

Using R, I have two columns (onset, duration) containing milliseconds in a data frame. I want to add a decimal point at the second mark for all data points in both columns i.e. turning 1541ms into 1.541s AND turning 638ms into 0.638s

Current data frame:

<kbd>Onset</kbd>       <kbd>Duration</kbd>
<kbd>1541</kbd>        <kbd>638</kbd>            
<kbd>41843</kbd>      <kbd>735</kbd>      
<kbd>61993</kbd>      <kbd>138</kbd>

I want:

<kbd>Onset</kbd>       <kbd>Duration</kbd>   
<kbd>1.541</kbd>        <kbd>0.638</kbd>            
<kbd>41.843</kbd>      <kbd>0.735</kbd>      
<kbd>61.993</kbd>      <kbd>0.138</kbd>

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks
Jon

Comment: you don't just want to divide by 1000?

Comment: Yes, i wanted my df kept intact too. Got it now, via: df$onset<-df$onset/1000. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
what_you_think_you_need <- function(x){
  s <- as.character(x)
  s[nchar(s)<4] <- sprintf("0%03d", x[nchar(s)<4])
  paste0(substr(s,1,nchar(s)-3),".",substr(s,nchar(s)-3,nchar(s)))
} 

what_you_actually_need <- function(x){
  x/1000
}
```

Use whichever one works best for you.

Comment: Got it now, via: df $ onset <- df $ onset /1000. Thanks!